Windows DEP error, "ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%p referenced memory at 0x%p. The memory could not be %s."
I've been trying to make a print function for windows in NASM, and I was able to get it to work as a linear program (no function calling) but when I tried to transfer the logic into a function and call it, I've ended up with some weird behavior. When I run it from the command line, it prints but then doesn't exit and crashes at that. When I tried to debug it, I couldn't even step into the first instruction; I would just get a DEP error. I've tried to get the exception context but that errors as well. Here is the code for my program.
11
    printCounted: ; void printCounted(char* buffer, int count) 
        
        
        mov  r10, QWORD gs:[0x60] ; get peb
        mov r10, [r10+0x20] ; get subsystem data
        mov r10, [r10+0x28] ; get stdout
        xor r8,r8 
        xor r9,r9
        push r8 ; push two NULLS onto stack
        push r8  
        push rdx ; push count parameter
        push rcx ; push buffer parameter
        lea rbx, io ; load io_status_block address into rbx
        push rbx ; push it onto stack
        sub rsp,40 ; make room for shadow stack
        mov eax, 0x8 ; 0x8 = NtWriteFile syscall
        syscall
        ret
    
    _main:
        xor eax, eax ; set eax to 0
        cpuid ; get processor brand string
        NOP
        shl rdx,  32 
        or rdx, rbx ; combine the two strings 
        push rcx ; pushing the two strings on to the stack, when combined make up the processor brand string
        push rdx 
        mov r13, rsp ; save location of string
        mov rcx, r13 ; put into rcx as buffer to printCounted
        mov rdx,12 ; put into rdx as count for printCounter
        call printCounted
        mov r10,0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF ; pseudohandle to current process
        mov eax, 0x2C ; 0x2c = NtTerminateProcess
        mov rdx, 0x90 ; exit code
        syscall 
    ```

